# javafx-autocomplete-field-1.0.jar compatibility issue

Tags: javafx

I downloaded javafx-autocomplete-field-1.0.jar and used it for my development work in jdk 1.8 environment. But I need to deploy this in 1.7 environment. If I do so, I'm getting "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: np/com/ngopal/control/AutoFillTextBox : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0". Is there an alternate jar for jdk1.7? Or is there anyway I can make this jar compatible in 1.7 environment? Please help.

Comment: You can download the [source code](https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-autocomplete-field), change the pom to compile it using Java 1.7 and then bundle it as a jar and use it in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try for this jar. I have checkout in previous commit it 
https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-autocomplete-field/commit/a92545e0fc33d0f54676e4fd27de743c5e0c5358 so please trythis jar
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xn01e5a3tm65mmz/AutoFillTextBox.jar?dl=0

Comment: thanks @Reegan..It is loading the page but the text field is not getting loaded when I point to jdk1.8 with this jar. I'm getting below error.

Jan 29, 2015 1:05:38 PM javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass
SEVERE: Failed to load skin 'np.com.ngopal.control.AutoFillTextBoxSkin' for control AutoFillTextBox@33207f[styleClass=autofill-text]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.<init>(Ljavafx/scene/control/Control;)V
 at np.com.ngopal.control.AutoFillTextBoxBehavior.<init>(AutoFillTextBoxBehavior.java:14)

Comment: Are you develop the project in netbeans means try this solution: 1,first checkout https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-autocomplete-field `git clone https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-autocomplete-field` and open this project in netbean and change the libraries 1.8 to 1.7,are remove error lib and replace the code.

Comment: Jdk 1.7 not available in "import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;" lib,In your jar , this class file "AutoFillTextBoxSkin" in extend of skinBase.

Comment: I replaced jfxrt.jar from jdk1.8 in my build path. This jar contains SkinBase class. After adding that, it is giving this error.

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/SkinBase

Comment: Naveen, hacking your build path to place different versions of jfxrt.jar in it is really inadvisable unless you really know what you are doing - it is not surprising that you would have development issues if you develop in such a way.  JavaFX is an integral part of the Java runtime and tied to a given Java runtime version, the binaries are built as a library which can be moved to a different runtime versions.  Perhaps a future modular JDK might allow JavaFX replacements, but Java 8 and 7 definitely do not.

Comment: The fx2 version isn't compatible in a fx8 development environment and the fx8 version won't run in fx2. You need a version that is compatible in both fx 2 and 8 !?

Answer (score 0):

You need a version that is compatible in both fx 2 and 8:

https://bitbucket.org/jugen/autofilltextbox/downloads